# Manually Select Database With Django's `clear()` command

Tags: django, django-models

I have a `ManyToMany` relationship between "dashboards" and "modules" in some code that I am trying to upgrade from Django 1.2 to 1.6.  I have a section in a view that was working in 1.2, but does not work in 1.6, where I am deleting a "module", but first trying to `clear()` its relationship to the "dashboards".

```
module = PortalAnalyticsTimeCountsModule.objects.using( DASHBOARD_DATABASE ).get( id = module_id )
module.dashboards.clear()
PortalAnalyticsTimeCountsModule.objects.using( DASHBOARD_DATABASE ).get( id = module_id ).delete( using = DASHBOARD_DATABASE )
```

where `DASHBOARD_DATABASE` is just a string that I set as a global value at the beginning of the file that is the name of the database the lines are supposed to use in these lines.  Note that `DASHBOARD_DATABASE` is not the `default` database for this django project set in the `settings.py` file, which is why I am manually setting the database using `using`.

In django 1.2, this worked fine.  In django 1.6, it is the `clear()` command that is giving me an error because it is using the `default` database instead of the database it is supposed to be using.  I cannot find a way to manually force that middle `clear()` line to use the correct database.

Does anybody know how (without referencing use of `ROUTERS`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, apparently the solution is to just remove

```
module.dashboards.clear()
```

entirely.  It doesn't seem to be necessary anymore to remove the connections.